# Set Emacs variable in .csv file to start org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want Emacs 24 to start in `org-mode` if I open this special `.csv` file, but id does not work

#### data.csv

```
| fruit  | stock |
| apple  | 1230  |
| banana |  200  |

# 
# eval: (org-mode)
# mode: org-mode
# End:
```

I must have misunderstood the variable mechanism in the end of the file. It would be nice, if i could tell Emacs **not to break lines** in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start the variable block with the line `Local Variables:`

```
| fruit  | stock |
| apple  | 1230  |
| banana |  200  |

# Local Variables:
# eval: (org-mode)
# mode: org-mode
# End:
```